# GEDI on GEE: Mismatched type for band 'beam'

Tags: google-earth-engine, lidar

I am trying to find, clip and download some GEDI data from GEE and I'm getting a casting error. My simple code is:

```
var GEDI = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
        .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-06-01','2021-12-31'))
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        
var GEDI_bands = GEDI.mean().toFloat()

var rh100 = GEDI_bands.select('rh100')
Map.addLayer(rh100, {min:0,max:20})
```

I'm sure I've attempted to fix this by using .toFloat() but I keep getting the error:

Layer 1: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with an incompatible band was encountered. Mismatched type for band 'beam':
Expected type: Integer.
Actual type: Float.
Image ID: 201908_036E_024S
This band might require an explicit cast.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why the 'beam' band is giving trouble. However, you can make use of a regular expression to select all the bands that are not 'beam' to avoid the error and continue with the clipping and exporting processes.

```
var GEDI_bands = GEDI.select('[^(beam)].*').mean();
```

Comment: Yeah looks like there's an issue with the 'beam' band. Your solution to get around it would work but I also found a way around it that allows me to keep the band

Comment: Could you post your workaround as an answer?

Comment: posted above :)

Answer (score 1):

This GEDI data is still under testing so there may be an issue with the 'beam' band. In the meantime, this worked:

```
var GEDI = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
        .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-06-01','2021-12-31'))
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        
var GEDI_bands = GEDI.map(function(img){
var int = img.select(['beam','degrade_flag']).toInt()
var float = img.select(['rh.*'])
return int.addBands(float)
}).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())

Map.addLayer(GEDI_bands, {min:0,max:20})
```